# High Torque Subtractors

Tags: technic, gears, mechanical

I would like to use a subtractor in my next RC LEGO tank, as it enables the vehicle to turn on the move, as opposed to stopping and then turning.

Unfortunately, the subtractors I have tested so far cannot withstand the torque of heavy vehicles, which either causes the subtractor to break apart, or the differentials/gears to grind.

Does anyone know any subtractor designs which are able to deal with high tension/torque/stress levels so that enormous vehicles can still use them? 3kg-5kg tolerance would be ideal.

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like you need a stronger differential.

Might I suggest [this design by Nazgarot](http://www.brickshelf.com/cgi-bin/gallery.cgi?f=508104):

[image]

If you make two, you can build a big and sturdy subtractor like this (probably customizing the gear ratios to your requirements, the right gearing could also remove the need for a PF switch):

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here's a video of it in action:

[image]

Comment: Very nice answer. You deserve to get the six-sided hat for this. :)

Comment: Excellent. I've come back to this question like 4 times hoping someone had finally figured out a decent answer.